# /etc/localtime is not a symbolic link

Tags: linux, fedora, timezone

According to `localtime` [from Linux manual page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/localtime.5.html):

> It should be an absolute or relative symbolic link pointing to
> /usr/share/zoneinfo/, followed by a timezone identifier such as
> "Europe/Berlin" or "Etc/UTC".

Here is the output of `ls -la /etc/localtime`, which is not a symbolic link, in my environment:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 724 Apr  3  2012 /etc/localtime
```

and for `cat /etc/localtime`

```
TZif2їԒazpҹӂ­ԣ౗<¿ֆfpם܈̰ݠYݪߵdpᖗ⸋p⿬㮠p䠱咥p悤鴘
                                                    따
                                                      셀촿퉰  ݉ 
νS~pCDTCSTTZif2) 
                  ÿÿÿÿtϰÿÿÿÿїԿÿÿÿѡzpÿÿÿÿҹÿÿÿÿӂ­ÿԚ:ÿÿÿÿԣ౿ÿÿÿռ¿ÿÿÿÿֆfpÿÿÿÿםÿÿڧÿۿ&ÿÿÿÿ܈̰ÿÿÿÿݠYÿÿÿÿݪÿݲsÿÿÿÿߵdpÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿᖗÿ᝸ÿÿÿÿ⸋pÿÿÿÿ⿬ÿÿÿÿ㮠pÿÿÿÿ䠱ÿÿÿÿ咥pÿÿÿÿ悤ÿÿÿÿ鴘ÿꤘÿÿÿÿ
    따ÿÿÿÿ
          셀ÿÿÿÿ촿ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ퉰 ݉ 
νSq羐LMTCDTCST
CST-8
```

My environment is Fedora 17 running on VirtualBox.

I copied the entire Fedora 17 image from someone else. In other words, I didn't build the environment from scratch.

I'm afraid of that it's a truly mistake, or it's made for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Likely what has happened is a copy of a zone file was made instead of a symbolic link or hard link.

You may be able to determine the source by comparing hashes of zone files installed on the system.

```
$ sha256sum /etc/localtime
821d6d97e3d34a3de2315279260e139adf484e581b4d187f8e6b532403b0f1c6  /etc/localtime

$ find /usr/share/zoneinfo/ -type f -exec sha256sum "{}" + |grep 821d6d97e3d34a3de2315279260e139adf484e581b4d187f8e6b532403b0f1c6
821d6d97e3d34a3de2315279260e139adf484e581b4d187f8e6b532403b0f1c6  /usr/share/zoneinfo/posix/America/Kentucky/Louisville
821d6d97e3d34a3de2315279260e139adf484e581b4d187f8e6b532403b0f1c6  /usr/share/zoneinfo/posix/America/Louisville
821d6d97e3d34a3de2315279260e139adf484e581b4d187f8e6b532403b0f1c6  /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Kentucky/Louisville
821d6d97e3d34a3de2315279260e139adf484e581b4d187f8e6b532403b0f1c6  /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Louisville
```

The "1" in your output of ls in the second field means there is 1 hard link to the file, so it's not a link to the same file as the original in the zoneinfo path.

On modern Fedora you can use timedatectl to either

```
timedatectl list-timezones
```

or

```
timedatectl set-timezone time_zone
```

Otherwise, simply ln -sf the appropriate zonefile from /usr/share/zoneinfo/ overwriting /etc/localtime (make a backup just in case!)

I doubt this situation is necessarily problematic, the reason that it's preferable to have a link instead of a copy is because software package updates might change the time rules. But this is Fedora 17, which is 10 years old...so it's not getting any updates ;)

Comment: it's worth reading some of the related questions on the side here too, i just learned about /etc/sysconfig/clock

Comment: on my Ubuntu (systemd 245), the `localtime(5)` man page says that "Because the timezone identifier is extracted from the symlink target name of /etc/localtime, this file may not be a normal file or hardlink." so I suppose it's possible that having it as a regular file could be at least sub-optimal.